# Does Covering Index Duplicate Data?

Tags: sql-server-2008, covering-index

Suppose we have this index

```
CREATE INDEX IX_test ON t1(c1) INCLUDE (c2)
```

Does this mean that we will have c2 in both index page and the actual data page? The real question is - does updating c2 mean that SQL Server will have to update IX_test and the actual data row (clustered index)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just like including any field in an index duplicates data. And all indexes (indices) that include a field have to be updated when the field changes.

So when you extend an index to cover a query (or more than 1), you are duplicating data. It's always a trade-of.

Answer (score 1):

Clustered index is a part of the table, so it's just updating the table itself. If it was non-clustered index then the answer would have been yes.

> CLUSTERED
>   Creates an index in which the logical order of the key values determines the physical order of the corresponding rows in a table. The bottom, or leaf, level of the clustered index contains the actual data rows of the table. A table or view is allowed one clustered index at a time. For more information, see Clustered Index Structures.

//edit:
I see I've understood it another way round. The point was that if you update a column you have to update:
1) clustered index
2) all non-clustered indexes containing that column

There's always a question when designing db what/how many indexes to create - it's a case of balance between reading and writing speed (and what's really needed).